# How can I take a screenshot of a website with PHP and GD?

Tags: php, gd

How can I create a screenshot of a website using PHP and the GD library.

Comment: Open challenge? This isn't a code-writing site.

Comment: You can use http://www.thumbshots.org/

Answer (score 5):

While you might be able to do something with [`imagegrabscreen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php) or [`imagegrabwindow`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php) you'd only be able to use it on a Windows box, and even then it would be tricky.

You'd have to open a browser window to the specified url (you could do that with `exec`) and grab a screenshot using the aforementioned methods.

Here's an example from the manual entry for [`imagegrabwindow`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php):

```
<?php
$browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
$handle = $browser->HWND;
$browser->Visible = true;
$browser->Navigate("http://www.libgd.org");

/* Still working? */
while ($browser->Busy) {
    com_message_pump(4000);
}
$im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
$browser->Quit();
imagepng($im, "iesnap.png");
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Ross,
the code above gives following error/Warning
PHP Warning: Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `InternetExplorer.Application': Access is denied. '

Comment: I'm having trouble even getting imagegrabscreen to work. As I said, I only copied that code from the manual. All I can suggest is that you follow the note on http://php.net/imagegrabscreen (assuming you're using Apache).

Comment: (Note that on Vista enabling Apache desktop support, restarting the service and the server still does not work)

Answer (score 1):

Website is rendered on client side, while PHP and GD are server side. You may also check [this website](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php) out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it works, expect that HTML5/canvas is not implemented. [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736196/903186) works better.