# Is it possible to 'snag' a web page image in PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

What I mean is to get the rendered HTML and make a Jpeg/GIF out of it. The idea is to make a digital snapshot of a page.

Comment: Different browsers render the same HTML differently...

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/733326#733326
wkhtml, pstohtml create both jpg or pdf from an html source (with css support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about HTML to a PDF? Many libraries available. And PDF's can in turn converted to Image?

That can be done right? Or am I way off?

Answer (score 1):

It will probably require far more effort than it is worth. Why not look at services that already provide this for you? (Like Alexa)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in PHP only ; but, from PHP, you can start a browser, indicating it that it has to load the URL you want, and, then, get a "screenshot" from that browser.

I've heard a couple of time of Firefox being able to do that -- should be a couple of questions+answers here on SO that should help you get started ; here are a couple of those :

- [Command line program to create website screenshots (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)
- [PHP: How to capture browser window screen with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952570/php-how-to-capture-browser-window-screen-with-php)
- [Is there a way to automatically take a screenshot of a website through a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109173/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-through-a-url)