# HTML to JPG using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a WYSIWYG Editor where a user can enter all the Text, make it bold, italic, change fonts etc.

What i want to do is, convert the HTML entered into WYSIWYG Editor to JPG.

Is it possible ? Any code ?

Comment: Sounds like you want `wkhtmltoimage` or another website screenshot tool.

Comment: If the HTML is basic, it might be easier to use any of the PHP [image processing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) APIs.  But please use PNG and not JPEG.

Comment: I am using an HTML WYSIWYG Editor so cant restrict the HTML from users perscpective. "wkhtmltoimage" is it a PHP library ?

Comment: It's an executable which you call from command line. There are PHP scripts to ease running it with the right functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically take a screenshot of a website through a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109173/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-through-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible..

You will need to create a php script that will just simply output that HTML nothing else eg. html.php?pageid={Dynamic ID }

Then you will need to download the wkhtmltoimage

After you download it set its path in the environment variables

Afterwards you will simply need to use this code to convert it to a image

```
 exec("wkhtmltoimage html.php?pageid=323 teset.jpg");
```

If you have any other queries let me know :)