# Take a screenshot every hour with cron

Tags: php, cron

I just discovered the site of [Phillip Mendonça-Vieira](http://okayfail.com/2011/nytimes-timelapse.html) who has inadvertantely taken a screenshot of the NYT twice an hour for the last year.

Anyone know how one could do this? I think it's a fantastic 'accident' he came up with. Just the basic idea would be great — I don't really know how you might even do this at the moment.

Thanks!

Terry

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is there a reason this is tagged as php or was that just an accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

You can use [HTMLTOPS](http://www.tufat.com/s%5Fhtml2ps%5Fhtml2pdf.htm) to render it to ps file, and then convert it to .jpg, .png, or something like, or you can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It uses Webkit.

You can link it with any free cron jobs, e.g. http://www.setcronjob.com/

Here is a tutorial for wkhtmltopdf: http://www.codediesel.com/php/taking-screenshots-of-websites-in-php/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a million for the help. I'll likely try and get in touch with the guy. Great idea.

Comment: This was forever ago, but I actually wrote about my whole process: http://okayfail.com/2011/howto-timelapse-nytimes.html

Answer (score 2):

According to his [reply on Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2779505), he used [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which I agree is an absolutely amazing library.

> [phillmv](http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=phillmv) 11 hours ago | [link](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2779505) | [parent](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2778847) | flag
>
> I used http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ . It's an amazing project
> that I try to use as often as possible, especially whenever a client
> requires pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask the guy for his script. (Via Twitter, Facebook, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the questions previously asked here:

[Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

[How can I take a screenshot of a website with PHP and GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627301/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-with-php-and-gd)